# How to reuse / reopen already closed variable_scope with name_scope in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to manage Tensors with variable_scope. The thing is every time the code snippet runs, it creates a new Tensor with index

for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
parameters = {}
with tf.variable_scope("layer1"):
    parameters["b1"] = tf.add(1,1)
with tf.variable_scope("layer1"):
    parameters["b2"] = tf.add(1,1)
print(parameters["b1"])
print(parameters["b2"])
```

you run the code multiple times, it will create

```
Tensor("layer1_1/Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("layer1_2/Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Tensor("layer1_3/Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("layer1_4/Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

....

How can I prevent this from happening ?

Solution:

So not closing-reopening the scope would solve part of the issue:

```
with tf.variable_scope("layer1"):
    parameters["b1"] = tf.add(1,1)
    parameters["b2"] = tf.add(1,1)
```

If you want to do some other things in between, and you must close the scope, then you can capture it like:

```
with tf.variable_scope("layer1") as s: # remembering scope in s
    [ create some tensors... ]
[ scope closed ]
with tf.variable_scope( s.original_name_scope ): # reopen same name scope again
    [ declare new variables within same name scope ]
```

This will share the name_scope between the two variable_scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your comment, your problem is that you want the naming scheme to be `layer1/Add_1`, then `layer1/Add_2` etc.

If that is your goal, then the problem with your code is that you use the `with` construct separately. The idea of "`with`" is that it automatically opens and closes the object you use it for. So `with tf.variable_scope( 'layer1' )` creates a variable scope with name `layer1` then closes it when you exit the `with`. Then you reopen another one, with the same name, and when it tries to create it, it will encounter the "same name" issue and will start index suffixing.

So not closing-reopening the scope would solve part of the issue:

```
with tf.variable_scope("layer1"):
    parameters["b1"] = tf.add(1,1)
    parameters["b2"] = tf.add(1,1)
```

If you want to do some other things in between, and you must close the scope, then you can capture it like:

```
with tf.variable_scope("layer1") as s: # remembering scope in s
    [ create some tensors... ]
[ scope closed ]
with tf.variable_scope( s.original_name_scope ): # reopen same name scope again
    [ declare new variables within same name scope ]
```

This will share the `name_scope` between the two `variable_scope`s.

> Tensor("layer1/Add:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
>
> Tensor("layer1/Add_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Comment: it suffix the variable_scope instead of tensor name (Add:0), so makes the tensorboard visualization very difficult. shouldn't variable_scope be like "namespace" ?

Comment: Rewrote my answer based on your comment. I'd suggest to add this comment, maybe an even clearer version, to the original question so people getting here would have an easier time understanding it. Also maybe change the question title to "How to reuse / reopen already closed variable_scope with name_scope in Tensorflow?"